# How to hide rows in Excel if all of the columns are not blank?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 10 columns.

The cells within the first 2 columns contain text and the remaining 8 cells contain 'blank', 0 or 1.

How can I hide all rows where the 8 columns do not contain any blank cells?

Comment: Is AutoFilter an option for you? There you can say show only "not blank" values. Guess its only called Filter in >=Office 2007

Comment: I believe (Auto)filter is not an option for this case, since rows need to be filtered using criteria based on more than one column here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy work-around:

1. Go to the empty column K.
2. Input the following function: `=COUNTIF(C2:K2;"")`and copy for entire column.
3. Blank cells will be counted.
4. **"8"** means all columns are empty for a particular row.
5. Use **filter on K** column to hide all "8" (to hide empty rows) or mark all numbers except "8" (to display empty rows only).

Comment: Great workaround - thanks! Please note it's a , instead of a ;. i.e. =COUNTIF(C2:K2,"")

Comment: You're welcome! :) Regarding ';' - well, it depends (just another country and another local settings). My Excel accepts semicolon as a arguments' separator only. But thanks for remark, I'll have in mind in future that there may be a difference here. Greetings from Poland! :)